# How to sort data from a .txt file?

Tags: database, arduino

I am storing two different sensor Values from an Arduino on a single SD file. It would look something like this:

x123,y234 (the format could be altered, if there is a better one)

I would like to be able to use this data (which will then contain a couple of thousand lines like that) and display it in, say an excel Diagram.

How could I do that? I can't just copy paste it... Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at CSV file format [here](http://edoceo.com/utilitas/csv-file-format)

for your case it would be like this.

```
x ,  y
123, 234
111, 222
..., ...
..., ...
```

I have tested this  on Open Office. And it will work for MS office also, i believe. see  [this example](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/01/convert-csv-excel/)